# Как перевести глобальные перменные в локальные?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Начал создавать телеграм бот и когда закончил решил проверить его роботу с помощю двух акк. После чего понял что бот роботает совсем не так как надо, а именно если два человека одновременно пользуються ботом, то кто первый ввел все нужные данные и нажал кнопку, то эти же данные виведут и второму человеку. Я понял причину почему это так работает, так как я обьявил все переменные глобально, а надо было сразу же локально. Теперь не могу понять как все поменять, что бы не затронуть логику бота. Вот частичный код программы

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["work"])
def start_work(message):
    global newphone, Numberphone, ListIDresponsibleroutes, ListNamereponsibleroutes, ordersname, sumaI1, ID, IDresponsibs, AllOverdueDebts, AllSumaDebts, ordersname, Debts, OverdueDebts, \
        nameformat, namecategory

    bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
    try:
        IDwithoutautori = message.from_user.id

        db = Client.TelegramUsers

        coll = db.Users

        searchdata = {"telegram_contact.user_id": IDwithoutautori}
        print(searchdata)

        search = coll.find_one(searchdata)

        autorizationforAPI['user_id'] = search.get('id')
        print(autorizationforAPI)
        autori = requests.post('URL', data=autorizationforAPI,
                               headers=headersforAPI2)
        print(autori)

        access_token = autori.json().get('access_token', [])

        print(access_token)

        headersforwork['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token
        headersforwork['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token
        autorizationforwork['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token

    except:
        print('not found')

    if autorizationforAPI['user_id']:

        del ListIDresponsibleroutes[:]
        del ListNamereponsibleroutes[:]
        del ordersname[:]
        del IDresponsibs[:]
        sumaI1 = 0
        ID = ""
        del AllOverdueDebts[:]
        del AllSumaDebts[:]
        del ordersname[:]
        del OverdueDebts[:]
        del Debts[:]
        nameformat = ""
        namecategory = ""
        del orders[:]

        print(ListNamereponsibleroutes)
        print(ListIDresponsibleroutes)
        print(ordersname)
        print("ID= " + ID)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Введите название Торговой точки, часть названия Торг.точки(пример 'маг'), адрес торг точки или просто символ(если он есть в название торг.точки(Пример '№')).")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_search)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Сначала надо авторизироваться с помощю команды /start. После чего ты сможешь начать роботать")


def get_search(message):
    global name, text, vendor, sumaI1, ListIDresponsibleroutes, ListNamereponsibleroutes, IDresponsibs, one

    bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')

    TTsearch["searchString"] = message.text
    pprint(TTsearch)

    url = 'URL'
    data = requests.post(url, json=TTsearch, headers=headersforwork)
    print(data)

    text = data.json().get('data', [])

    for i in range(len(text)):
        name = text[i]['name']
        # vendor = text[i]['vendorId']
        address = text[i]['location']['addressLine']
        pprint(name)

        sumaI1 += i

    print(sumaI1)

    selectKeyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

    if text:
        if sumaI1 == 0:
            for i in range(len(text)):
                one = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[0]['name']) + "  " + str(text[0]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="first")

            sumaI1 = 0
            print(sumaI1)
            selectKeyboard.add(one)


        elif sumaI1 == 1:
            for i in range(len(text)):
                one = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[0]['name']) + "  " + str(text[0]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="first")
                two = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[1]['name']) + "  " + str(text[1]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="second")

            sumaI1 = 0
            print(sumaI1)
            selectKeyboard.add(one, two)

        elif sumaI1 == 3:
            for i in range(len(text)):
                one = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[0]['name']) + "  " + str(text[0]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="first")
                two = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[1]['name']) + "  " + str(text[1]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="second")
                three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[2]['name']) + "  " + str(text[2]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="three")

            sumaI1 = 0
            print(sumaI1)
            selectKeyboard.add(one, two, three)

        elif sumaI1 == 6:
            for i in range(len(text)):
                one = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[0]['name']) + "  " + str(text[0]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="first")
                two = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[1]['name']) + "  " + str(text[1]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="second")
                three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[2]['name']) + "  " + str(text[2]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="three")
                four = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[3]['name']) + "  " + str(text[3]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="four")

            sumaI1 = 0
            print(sumaI1)
            selectKeyboard.add(one, two, three, four)

        elif sumaI1 == 10:
            for i in range(len(text)):
                one = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[0]['name']) + "  " + str(text[0]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="first")
                two = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[1]['name']) + "  " + str(text[1]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="second")
                three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[2]['name']) + "  " + str(text[2]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="three")
                four = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[3]['name']) + "  " + str(text[3]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="four")
                five = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[4]['name']) + "  " + str(text[4]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="five")

            sumaI1 = 0
            print(sumaI1)
            selectKeyboard.add(one, two, three, four, five)



        elif sumaI1 == 15:
            for i in range(len(text)):
                one = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[0]['name']) + "  " + str(text[0]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="first")
                two = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[1]['name']) + "  " + str(text[1]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="second")
                three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[2]['name']) + "  " + str(text[2]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="three")
                four = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[3]['name']) + "  " + str(text[3]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="four")
                five = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[4]['name']) + "  " + str(text[4]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="five")
                six = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[5]['name']) + "  " + str(text[5]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="six")

            sumaI1 = 0
            print(sumaI1)
            selectKeyboard.add(one, two, three, four, five, six)

        elif sumaI1 == 21:
            for i in range(len(text)):
                one = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[0]['name']) + "  " + str(text[0]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="first")
                two = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[1]['name']) + "  " + str(text[1]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="second")
                three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[2]['name']) + "  " + str(text[2]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="three")
                four = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[3]['name']) + "  " + str(text[3]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="four")
                five = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[4]['name']) + "  " + str(text[4]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="five")
                six = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[5]['name']) + "  " + str(text[5]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="six")
                seven = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[6]['name']) + "  " + str(text[6]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="seven")

            sumaI1 = 0
            print(sumaI1)
            selectKeyboard.add(one, two, three, four, five, six, seven)

        elif sumaI1 == 28:
            for i in range(len(text)):
                one = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[0]['name']) + "  " + str(text[0]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="first")
                two = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[1]['name']) + "  " + str(text[1]['location']['addressLine']), callback_data="second")
                three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[2]['name']) + "  " + str(text[2]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="three")
                four = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[3]['name']) + "  " + str(text[3]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="four")
                five = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[4]['name']) + "  " + str(text[4]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="five")
                six = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[5]['name']) + "  " + str(text[5]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="six")
                seven = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[6]['name']) + "  " + str(text[6]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="seven")
                eight = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(text[7]['name']) + "  " + str(text[7]['location']['addressLine']),
                    callback_data="eight")

            sumaI1 = 0
            print(sumaI1)
            selectKeyboard.add(one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите Торговую точку:  ",
                         reply_markup=selectKeyboard)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ничего не найдено")
```

Пробовал уже написать все переменные локально и возращать через `return`, но это не роботает. Также пробовал через поля класса, но по образцам которые нашел в интернете(сам плохо знаю классы в python) это не тоже не помогло. Пожалуйста подскажите что можно сделать в таком случае, что бы бот розличал что и кому отправлять

Comment: Заведите БД, в Питоне встроена поддержка `sqlite3`

Comment: `Как перевести глобальные перменные в локальные?` - просто не писать глобальные, а писать локальные.

Comment: @Dareten использую Mongo DB

Comment: @ And если бы все так просто было. Так как есть переменные которые должные быть глобальные потому что они используються в других функц, а возращать их из другой функций  методом `return` мне не помогло

Comment: Для этого существует ООП

Comment: @Key Переменные могут иметь одинаковые имена и значения в разных областях видимости. Если Вам нужна локальная переменная с глобальным значением - просто создайте её, например так: `x = globals()['x']`. «Пространства имён — отличная вещь! Давайте будем делать их больше!» - «The Zen of Python»